# Rails 2.x http basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I'm trying to get basic http authentication working on my Rails app. I'm offering a simple REST interface served by a Rails server, only xml/json output.

Every method needs authentication, so I put the authenticate filter in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
  before_filter :authenticate

protected
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |u, p|
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Even with having the method return true, I'm receiving a 401 from the server:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/myresource/1.xml -i
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
Cache-Control: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Application"
X-Runtime: 1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 27
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.1/2010-01-10)
Date: Thu, 03 Jun 2010 02:43:55 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP Basic: Access denied.
```

If I'm explicitly returning true, yet getting served a 401.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify a login/password pair, even if you don't check them

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/myresource/1.xml -i -u username:password
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can display an xml builder view in the event a user does not provide a login/password pair? I want to give a descriptive error message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show an error message for XML requests you can write your own `before_filter`:

```
class ApplicationController < ApplicationController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    authentication_procedure = lambda do |username, password|
      # test username and password
    end
    authenticate_with_http_basic(&authentication_procedure) ||
      request_http_basic_authentication_or_show_xml_error(&authentication_procedure)
  end

  def request_http_basic_authentication_or_show_xml_error(&auth_proc)
    if request.format == Mime::XML
      render :action => '/errors/401'
    else
      request_http_basic_authentication('My Realm')
    end
  end
end
```

Then put something into `app/views/errors/401.xml.builder`.